# Tooltip positioned too high with data-bs-placement="top" in Bootstrap 5

Tags: html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-5

Recently, I upgraded a project from Bootstrap 4 to 5 and encountered an issue with tooltips. When I use placement left, right, or bottom, the tooltip is perfectly positioned on the component. However, when I use placement top, the tooltip appears too high.

I've noticed that if my navbar switches to phone mode, the tooltip placement changes, but only for the 'top' position; it remains unaffected for others.

I adjusted my footer size to keep the tooltip in place, but now, if my navbar switches to phone mode, the tooltip appears too high again.

For this I removed "position: absolute" from the footer component.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set one of the 'boundary' or 'container' options that helps control the positioning of the tooltip relative to its parent element and the boundaries.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/tooltips/#options

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the fast response!

I've just tried changing the 'boundary' and 'container' with no success.

My suspicion is that there's something more hidden within the project which I'm not aware of, because the left, right, and bottom placements work perfectly.

I still don't understand why the height of the body affects only this "top" placement.

Comment: is there following instruction at the top of your html? <!DOCTYPE HTML>

Comment: Yes, the following instruction is inside the document, at the top.